# Не срабатывает событие на изменения свойства "checked"

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" id="MyCheckBox" onchange="alert('ok!');" />  
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("MyCheckBox").checked = false;
</script>
```

Почему когда программно меняешь свойство "checked", событие "onchange" не срабатывает?

Comment: Решил проблему через DOM Посмотрите мой новый код и поставте галочку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function func(){
alert('ok!');
}
 ipt=document.createElement("input");
 ipt.type="checkbox";
 ipt.id="MyCheckBox";
 ipt.onchange=func;
 document.body.appendChild(ipt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ps: Не забудьте поставить галочку рядом с ответом, а то ваш вопрос висит в "неотвеченных".

Comment: Сделал, но всё равно, если по нему тыкать, всё работает, а когда меняешь свойство, событие не вызывается ((, галочка ставится а событие не хочет(

Comment: А вы напишите и вызывайте вашу функцию самостоятельно!

Comment: да но всё равно он мне не потходит

Answer (score 1):

А где у вас вызывается change()? Если вы вешаете события через атрибут, пишите примерно так:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="MyCheckBox" onclick="alert(this.checked);" checked />  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById("MyCheckBox");
    el.checked = false;
    if(typeof el.onclick === 'function')
        el.onclick();
</script>
```

Comment: через атрибут на сервере а если if(typeof el.onchange === 'function') как с этим быть что IE ни хочет вызывать el.onchange()

Comment: Обновил код. Так работает?

Comment: нет
я тут нашёл
    if (document.createEvent && obj.dispatchEvent) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
       obj.dispatchEvent(evt); // for DOM-compliant browsers
       obj.checked = false;
   } else if (obj.fireEvent) {
     obj.fireEvent("onclick"); // for IE
     obj.checked = false;
   }
но FF чёт ни хочет возвращает true что выполнил но не вызвал

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="MyCheckBox" onchange="alert('ok!');" checked="checked" />
<script>document.getElementById("MyCheckBox").click();</script>
```